# Lua - equivalent to extern

Tags: lua, extern

Is there any variable in lua equivalent to extern variables in C++ ??

I want to be able to define the variables in one script and read/use those values in another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Scope Tutorial](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ScopeTutorial) on lua-users wiki,

> Any variable not defined as `local` is in the *global scope*. Anything in the global scope is accessible by all inner scopes.

For your question; let's say I've files **`one.lua`** and **`two.lua`**

### one.lua

```
local x = 3
y = 17
```

### two.lua

```
dofile( "one.lua" )
print( x, y )
```

---

The output shall be

```
nil        17
```

If you're still unsure if some variable will be `local` or `global`; you can use `_G` table for them. Like this:

```
_G.y = 17      -- Same as y = 17 in one.lua
```

Answer (score 3):

They are called *global variables*. Any variable that is used without being declared local is global.

In other words, this is the default already. You don't have to do anything special.